# Issue with session varaibles in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using CI3 , i am storing session variables in one controller and passing it to another and it was working fine for some days but suddenly the session variables are not set and values are not pasing to controller , I have not changed anything in the code.. I don know how to debug the issue which is causing trouble

one controller

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
   'value1'       =>$this->input->post('value1'),
   'value2'       =>$this->input->post('value2'),
                ));
```

getting values in second controller

```
 echo  $this->session->userdata('value1');
```

The value is coming as null

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how did you set session data.

Comment: @vellaidurai so to set session data you should post a form or something according to your code example.did you do it first?

Comment: yes i have done that .. i everyting works fine before suddenly its not working .. I have checked the logs nothing is in there

Comment: When you are setting session you are setting an array and you are directly accessing value1 as individual variable

Comment: @SunilPachlangia in codeigniter it is valid

Comment: Which session driver are you using - files? database?, other?

Comment: $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';

Comment: Many people seem to be having this problem but nobody has been able to reproduce the behavior consistently. It might be a bug in PHP or possibly in CI. I was able to cure this by making sure that `$this->load->library('session');` was the last library loaded in the problem controller's constructor. This is a voodoo fix but (knock on wood) it is working so far.

Answer (score 2):

Have you double-checked that value1 is getting posted to your controller and is not null? Try echoing a var_dump of value1 right before you throw it into your array and see what the value is.

```
echo var_dump($this->input->post('value1'));
```

EDIT:

Does controller 2 extend the default CI controller, some other controller, or is standalone? It might be that it is unaware of the session altogether. Try adding

```
$this->ci =& get_instance();
```

in the constructor of the controller and then try calling it using

```
echo $this->ci->session->all_userdata();
```

Comment: it is setting in value1 i have checked it

Comment: Where are you storing session data? And is the session library being loaded/autoloaded?

Comment: it is loaded in the controller